# How to install own paid app (version released in iTunes) on own iPhone

Tags: iphone, installation

Maybe I overlooked something, but I have a small problem:
I just released a paid app to the App Store, and now I'd like to install this app on my own device, so it exactly mimics the behavior as if I would have bought it from the App Store.

The problem is: If I install it from xCode, it will log in to the Sandbox of the Game Center, not to the real Game Center. And iTunes of course tells me to pay for it when I want to get it :-).

Do I have to use a promo code or even buy it myself just to get it on my device just like a user? Or is there any more elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: You do realize all you have to do is update the app to get new codes right?

Comment: If you don't have any promo-codes, just buy it from yourself. It can't be so expensive you'd be unwilling to spend 30% of the price to have your own copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only elegant solution would be to give yourself a promo code.

Comment: I was afraid so *sigh*. so one of the 50 promo codes has to go to myself then ... don't want to spend 30 cent on getting my own app :-).

Comment: Why not? Isn't it worth it? ;-)

Comment: LOL ... no, don't want to give another 30 cent to Apple :-)

Answer (score 1):

You would need a promo code here.

What you should do the simulate a real user buying it, is delete all the provisioning profiles from the phone. Delete the application  that you built from xcode and redeem the code.

Thats how I do it at least.

Comment: Its choose one or the other here. 30cents (maybe more) or 1/50 codes.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no other way, as far as I know. And even then the sandbox problem could remain. Then you have to restore your iphone, i think.

Comment: with a promo code the sandbox problem should not exist - I assume the version is the normal app store version (not to mix up with ad-hoc test versions which of course use the sandbox)

Comment: Yes, it SHOULD. But... I had the problem once that this did not change the sandbox issue. Even the other apps only ran in Game Center sandbox mode. Good luck.

Comment: In that case logging out of game center (click on your name in the game center main screen and choose log out) and then log in again solves the issue most of the time - of course until you start up a test app again, which will switch you to sandbox mode for all other apps again until you log out in game center again.